# Mailgun Inline images, how does it work?

Tags: php, inline, mailgun

I'm working with mailgun and want to add images to my newsletters.
Now I did this:

```
$mg->sendMessage($domain, array('from'    => 'developer@mijnprojectgroep.eu', 
                                'to'      => 'developer@mijnprojectgroep.eu', 
                                'subject' => 'Developers Mail Test MijnProjectgroep batch #1', 
                                'text'    => 'Hallo %recipient_fname%,


                'html'    => '<html>
<img style="display:block;" class="img1" src="cid:header-clip.png" width="600" height="64" />
</html>',
array('inline' => '@.././images/newsletter/header-clip.png'),

'o:tracking-opens' => 'yes'));
```

But no images are loading while I receive the newsletter.
The document with the script above is in:

Root --> /MailGun/

The images are in:

Root --> /images/newsletter/

Also tried: @../../images/newsletter/header-clip.png

The documentation is here:

http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html?highlight=html#sending-via-api

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure this out in the end?

Answer (score 4):

You did not do wrong. Actually there is an issue in the API documentation.

**You need to use an array instead of string path in inline image path**. It will solve the issue. You can add it like this:

```
$mg->sendMessage($domain, array('from'    => 'developer@mijnprojectgroep.eu',
                                    'to'      => 'developer@mijnprojectgroep.eu', 
                                    'subject' => 'Developers Mail Test MijnProjectgroep batch #1',
                                    'text'    => 'Hallo %recipient_fname%,
                                    'html'    => '<html><img style="display:block;" class="img1" src="cid:header-clip.png" width="600" height="64" /></html>',
    array('inline' => array('@.././images/newsletter/header-clip.png') 
),
    'o:tracking-opens' => 'yes'));
```

**Please check this line:**

```
array('inline' => array('@.././images/newsletter/header-clip.png')
```

Comment: i can send single embedded image. but i have multiple embedded image then how can do it. and i have some text content then image then some text and then image. how can i dynamically embed image.

Comment: You can follow this link to view how to send complete html:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786128/how-to-send-out-html-email-with-mailgun/24877620#24877620

Answer (score 1):

The images to be attached need to be passed in as the 3rd argument to the sendMessage method:

```
    $mgClient->sendMessage("$domain",
              array('from'    => 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox.mailgun.org>',
                    'to'      => 'mr awesome <mrawesome@web.com>',
                    'subject' => 'Hello Mr',
                    'html' => '<html><img style="display:block;" class="img1" src="cid:header-clip.png" width="600" height="64" /></html>'
              ),
              array (
                'inline' => array(dirname(__FILE__).'/images/newsletter/header-clip.png')
              )
      );
```

Also note the file path to the file: `dirname(__FILE__)`. You may need to change this to suit.

An example is also found in the Mailgun docs, under the heading "Sending Inline Images" - https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-api

Answer (score 0):

To embed an image in your html code, you need to set an `inline` property to parameters array. This `inline` property expects a `filePath` and a `fileName`. Example:

```
$mgClient->messages()->send($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'developer@mijnprojectgroep.eu',
    'to'      => 'developer@mijnprojectgroep.eu',
    'subject' => 'Developers Mail Test MijnProjectgroep batch #1',
    'text'    => 'Hallo %recipient_fname%',
    'html'    => '<html><img style="display:block;" class="img1" src="cid:header-clip.png" width="600" height="64" /></html>',
    'inline' => array(
        array(
            'filePath' => 'path/to/images/newsletter/header-clip.png',
            'filename' => 'header-clip.png'
        )
    ),
    'o:tracking-opens' => 'yes'
));
```

If you need to add more than one image, just add an `inline` property for each image.

```
$mgClient->messages()->send($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'developer@mijnprojectgroep.eu',
    'to'      => 'developer@mijnprojectgroep.eu',
    'subject' => 'Developers Mail Test MijnProjectgroep batch #1',
    'text'    => 'Hallo %recipient_fname%',
    'html'    => '
    <html>
       <img style="display:block;" class="img1" src="cid:image1.png" width="600" height="64" />
    </html>
    <html>
       <img style="display:block;" class="img1" src="cid:image2.png" width="600" height="64" />
    </html>',
    'inline' => array(
        array(
            'filePath' => 'path/to/images/newsletter/image1.png',
            'filename' => 'image1.png'
        )
    ),
    'inline' => array(
        array(
            'filePath' => 'path/to/images/newsletter/image2.png',
            'filename' => 'image2.png'
        )
    ),
    'o:tracking-opens' => 'yes'
));
```

Notice that I've added a new `img` tag for new image.
Make sure you have a `cid:image_name` added to `src` attribute for each image.

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to just enter the details as:

```
$header = FCPATH."public_html/assets/img/newsletter_header.png";

$mg->messages()->send($domain, [
  'from'    => 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
  'to'      => 'yyyyy <yyyyyyyy@gmail.com>',
  'subject' => 'The PHP SDK is awesome!',
  'html'    =>  $html,
  'inline' => array(
    array('filePath' => $header)
  )
]);
```

And in your HTML code:

```
$imageName = "newsletter_header.png";
<img src="cid:'.$imageName.'" width="408" height="100" alt="Pedul" border="0"
class="em_w150" />
```

For this you have to take care of 2 points:

1. in inline tag add the full path of your image
2. In your HTML code add only image name of file.

Comment: Please format your answer and explain how it differs from the other 6-year-old answers for the question.