# How to add an inline image to a HTML template

Tags: mailgun, inline-images, html-templates

In mailgun,  am trying to have an HTML template that includes images. The images are static so they don't change from one email to another.

When adding the HTML code in the mailgun's template preview, the images are shown properly. However when the email is sent, the images are not shown. Anyone had that issue and was able to solve it?

Comment: I assume you are only sending the html and not the image (which is a separate file). Also with a quick google I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990031/mailgun-inline-images-how-does-it-work

Comment: The images are static so no need to add them in the code. The idea is to separate the visuals from code and give the designers as much freedom. That means the images are embedded in the HTML as base64 encoded images.

Comment: Ah, I see. Btw by embedding the images into the code, I think you are rather taking away the freedom from the designers. Anyways, are you able to retrieve the raw html that was received? Maybe there's some security implemented in the recipient mail client that blocks inline images?

Comment: @Papooch the question might be related but there's no context there, also it seems like a language-specific problem!